# Want to read gateway properties from config server

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-config, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a spring cloud gateway in my project and I want to use config server with that.

What exactly I want to do is

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tZ5mQ.png)

I want to read these highlighted values from config server.
i kept these values in config server, still it reads the values from application property not from config,,,, Can som1 plz help here

when i use @value to read these values then it takes config server values...
Is it like config server only works with @value????

Comment: No, but without more information from you it is hard to see why. Please add the versions you are using, your dependencies and your configuration

Comment: @spencergibb I am using spring-cloud-services-starter-config-client  version 3.2.1.release and for spring gateway we are using spring-cloud-starter-gateway version 3.0.2 ..

Comment: It should work. If you are using  spring cloud services on PAS/TAS you should contact support. Otherwise can you provide a sample? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: spring:
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
      - id: employeeModule
        uri: http://localhost:8081/
        predicates:
        - Path=/employee/**
      - id: consumerModule
        uri: http://localhost:8082/
        predicates:
        - Path=/consumer/**
I want to read these uri values from config server

Comment: @Ankit were you able to read the routes configuration from config server?